# Capturing whether keycode 66 is associated with Hyper_L in bash script

Tags: bash, xmodmap

I want to check whether `keycode 66` is associated with `Hyper_L` by calling `xmodmap -pke | grep "Hyper"` and storing in a variable in a bash script.

What can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really sure what output you are looking for but this will tell you the value of the `key` variable after it determines what keycode it is set to:

```
#!/bin/bash

key=$(xmodmap -pke | grep "Hyper_L" | awk '{print $2}')

echo "Keycode for Hyper_L is $key"
```

Example:

```
terrance@terrance-ubuntu:~$ ./key_check.bsh 
Keycode for Hyper_L is 207
```